# Ошибки при компиляции Masonry WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013

Хочу использовать Masonry WPF. Скачал с Гитхаба по этой ссылке: https://github.com/Lizzaran/WPF-Masonry

Изменений в коде я вообще никаких не делал.
При сборке (build) вылетают ошибки:

[image: Ошибки при компиляции Masonry WPF]

Что я делаю не правильно?
Может надо сначала что-то подключить, а потом компилировать?

Comment: Вероятнее всего у вас не установлен `.NET v4.5.2`. Тут есть два пути - установить новую версию дотнета или изменить код для более старой версии.

Comment: С проблемой разобрались?

Comment: Совершенно замотался.... Проблему решил тем, что отказался от Masonry и прыгал с бубном с стандартными панелями WPF. У меня установлена версия 4.5.1 и 4.6. Версию 4.5.2 установить не получилось, так как установка прекращается, когда установщик находит на компьютере более свежую версию.